# Django view/html input - Can I force an update using submit when no form update is present?

Tags: html, django, forms, view, form-submit

Is it possible to force a refresh of a template using a html form from the form itself when it appears no form updates are present?
Here is a simple example of what I thought was a valid use case.

A view generates a random number:-

```
def test_random_view(request):
    varid=randint(1,1000)
    context={
        "Randomid": varid
    }
    return render(request ,'test_random.html', {'context': context})
```

A simple page is supposed to generate this random number:-

```
This doesn't work<br><br>
Here is a random number: <br>
{{ context.Randomid }}
<form method='get' action=''>
    <input type="text" name="input"  value="Here is an empty field"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update the random number"><br>
</form>
```

But on clicking the submit button the random number will not update. I'm assuming this is because it recognises that no update has been made to the form so it doesn't pass back to the view to generate a new random number.
You can "trick" it by passing the random number into a text input:-

```
This sort of works<br><br>
Here is a random number: <br>
<form method='get' action=''>
    <input type="text" name="input"  value={{ context.Randomid }}><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Update the random number"><br>
</form>
```

But there is no reason for this text field to exist other than to force the form to recognise the update and pass back to the view.

What's a better way to do this?

Should I be creating the form in forms.py and then creating the instance of the form in the view? If so, how do I ensure the page will refresh?

Can it be done appropriately in the page itself?

Incidentally, the application of this is for the user to select an item off the list with random being at the top of the selection and then click for an actual selection or click repeatedly for as many random suggestions as they would like.

Thanks for your help

Phil

Comment: If I get it right, you need a `generate random` button, and a `submit` button, why aren't you using JS to generate the random number, since the whole `random thing` happens on the client? And then have a separate submit button that will send this number to your backend.

Comment: Thanyou @xpy. I don't know any JS. The random number needs to correspond to an id field within a data model and hence retrieve an object at random. So the actual random number comes from a separate view `def random_cons_view():
    #returns a random constituency id
    varrandto=constituency.objects.all().count()
    varrandid=randint(1,varrandto)
    return varrandid` So, I'm making use of Django here to control the range of the random number which seems valid to include in the view itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually Django doesn't cache your views and any `GET` request should return a fresh response. For some reason it seems you are seeing a cached response. This might be your browser, or some server in between (nginx?).

If you want to prevent a Django HTTP response from ever being cached the easiest way to do so is by decorating it with the `never_cache` decorator: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.cache.never_cache

Comment: So I added `from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache` at the top of views and then `@never_cache` before the view in question. It wasn't obvious that the view was cached, and I still don't know why it happens. I'm hosted at "a2hosting.com", perhaps that's the way it's set up on their side. Bear in mind I'm seriously new to all this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to brute force a refresh on the page you could simply use an anchor tag with a link leading back to this page:

if for example your urls.py looks like this:
...

```
path('random/', views.test_random_view, name='random'),
```

...

Your template would look like this:

```
This doesn't work<br><br>
Here is a random number: <br>
{{ context.Randomid }}
<a href="{% url 'random' %}">Reset</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @Alex_D. A brute refresh would lose a valid selection wouldn't it? So it would work for this which I appreciate but for the wider application which I mention, the user couldn't select anything else.